# Nutch regex-urlfilter syntax

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

I am running Nutch v. 1.6 and it is crawling specific sites correctly, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct for the file `NUTCH_ROOT/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt`.

The site I want to crawl has a URL similar to this:

```
http://www.example.com/foo.cfm
```

On that page there are numerous links that match the following pattern:

```
http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/Bar_-_Foo/Extra/EX/20817/ID=6976
```

I want to crawl links that match second example above as well. In my `regex-urlfilter.txt` I have the following:

```
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm$
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/(.+)*$
```

Nutch matches on the first one and crawls it correctly, but does not seem to pick up links using the other filter. How can I get Nutch to crawl URL's like the second one above?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/(.+)*$
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/(.)*$
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/.+$
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/(.*)*$
```

In my `NUTCH_ROOT/urls/nutch` I have:

```
http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#What_happens_if_I_inject_urls_several_times.3F you can't have multiple URLs (they will be ignored). What about to put **only**:

```
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm/(.+)*$
```

which should cover your first line: `+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm$` as well, or, if there are problems with `/`, try:

```
+^http://www.example.com/foo.cfm//?(.+)*$
```

Where `//?` should stand for character `/` or

Comment: On both of your suggestions I get: `Stopping at depth=1 - no more URLs to fetch.`, so I am not sure why it isn't working. That FAQ looks like a good read though.

Comment: @NicYoung so does it mean that it is working for depth 0? hmm, i found several posts about your error message: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Simple-crawl-fails-to-find-any-URLs-td614603.html (2nd post); or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710492/nutch-does-not-crawl-says-stopping-at-depth-1-no-more-urls-to-fetch

Comment: Thanks for catching the multiple URLs in the FAQ.