# How to set up regex in nutch for filtering URL of techcrunch?

Tags: regex, nutch

I want to crawl the pages of Techcrunch uploaded after the 1 Jan of 2013.The website follows the pattern

```
             http://www.techcrunch.com/YYYY/MM/DD
```

So my question is how to setup the regex in urlfilter in nutch so that i could crawl only pages which i want.

```
             +^http://www.techcrunch.com/2013/dd/dd/([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nutch but do you try:

```
+^http://www.techcrunch.com/2013/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}.*$
```

or

```
+^http://www.techcrunch.com/2013/[0-9]+/[0-9]+.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions will match the URLs you need:

**Without groups**

```
http:\/\/www.techcrunch.com\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\w+
```

**With groups**

```
http:\/\/www.techcrunch.com\/(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\w+)
```

*I didn't put anchors (`^$`), but you can put them if you need them for the filtering.*

Try them to see if any of them work.

I don't know how nutch works, but a couple of suggestions about your regex that may apply: the `/` in the regexp should be escaped; the `dd` parts should be `\d\d` so they match two digits.

About setting up the regex, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884249/nutch-regex-urlfilter-syntax) to see if it helps you.