# Nutch to allow when the host name is having portnumber

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am using nutch to push and index  data to solr. In nutch, i have added **abc.com:85** to **domain-urlfilter.txt**  and **+^[http://abc\.com\:85](http://abc%5C.com%5C:85)** to **regex-urlfilter.txt**.

The problem is that nutch is not indexing data and it is throwing this message **Total number of urls rejected by filters:1**

Here in the url, i need the portnumber ,this configuration is done.

Could you please let me know how to make nutch work with the port number :85 added.

Comment: Any inputs from anyone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the syntax: `+^http://abc\.com\:85` is not correct. Please check the syntax here: [Nutch regex-urlfilter syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884249/nutch-regex-urlfilter-syntax)

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do